# Uncaught Type Error when accessing JSON data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have the following JSON data:

```
const randomData = 
    [
      {
        gender: 'male',
        name: {
          title: 'Mr',
          first: 'Blake',
          last: 'Li',
        },
      },
    ];
```

When I attempt to access the `first name` property using `name = randomData[0].name.first`, I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'first')`

Comment: I've tried your code and I see no error. To be sure move the array opening brace at the same line of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are consuming an API, that would have the following JSON structure, because your mock example are just fine to do what you want.

And prob what is happening is that some of ur data doens't have value in `name` object.

So you would need to make a check when trying to access `name.first`.

ex:

`const name = randomData[0].name.first || 'No name'`

`const name = randomData[0].name && randomData[0].name.first`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a JSON validator every-time you get data to verify that structure you expect is correct. I built a small (21kBs) but powerful JSON validator: https://www.npmjs.com/package/great-json-validator

Validating the structure of incoming data will guarantee you won't get this type of errors.